# Jasper Report : Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have designed jasper report using `iReport` version (4.7.1). Through iReport it works fine. When I called from java servlet, I get an error:

```
Error : `Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null".`

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Document root element "jasperReport", 
must match DOCTYPE root "null".

        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:242)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:225)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:213)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:167)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:151)
        at com.crmreport.controller.ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:124)
        at com.crmreport.controller.ReportServlet.doPost(ReportServlet.java:505)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:165)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "jasperReport",must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Err
orHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootEleme
ntSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleSta
rtElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElem
ent(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1357)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$Conten
tDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1289)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3084)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$Prolog
Driver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(X
MLDocumentScannerImpl.java:645)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
ML11Configuration.java:807)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
ML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.
java:107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Ab
stractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:
238)
```

This is my JRXML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
              name="BusinessUnitDetail" 
              pageWidth="595" 
              pageHeight="842" 
              columnWidth="535" 
              leftMargin="20" 
              rightMargin="20" 
              topMargin="20"
              bottomMargin="20" 
              uuid="22e233b2-d42c-4a93-87c6-a1d23bd3f7ca">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="dateFrom" class="java.util.Date">
        <property name="dateFrom" value="new java.util.Date()"/>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="dateTo" class="java.util.Date">
        <property name="dateTo" value="new java.util.Date()"/>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     BusinessUnit AS BusinessUnit,
     CallStart AS CallStart,
     CallEnd AS CallEnd,
     CallTakenBy AS CallTakenBy,
     CalledDate AS CalledDate,
     CallPersonName AS CallPersonName,
     Duration AS Duration
FROM
    crmcalldetail
WHERE CalledDate > $P{dateFrom} AND CalledDate < $P{dateTo}
ORDER BY BusinessUnit]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="BusinessUnit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CallStart" class="java.sql.Time"/>
    <field name="CallEnd" class="java.sql.Time"/>
    <field name="CallTakenBy" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CalledDate" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="CallPersonName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Duration" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="duration_sum" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="BusinessUnit" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Duration}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="duration_tot" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Duration}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="BusinessUnit">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{BusinessUnit}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="37">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement uuid="e53feaa2-4fce-4233-873c-4c5b1d87bd09" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="7" width="555" height="24" forecolor="#B89F7D" backcolor="#000000"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement uuid="8a34951d-becf-4676-801f-1cbfd81518b9" style="SubTitle" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="2" y="0" width="479" height="24" forecolor="#FF6600"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{BusinessUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="26">
                <textField pattern="###0">
                    <reportElement uuid="6a2e9f4f-bc0c-4deb-a861-9d30221cc566" x="481" y="9" width="48" height="15" forecolor="#FF3300"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="11" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{duration_sum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="194" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement uuid="97326b0b-4f59-45fa-bab1-82019da4a8f6" x="456" y="0" width="99" height="117"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["cherry.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="643a9f59-1f72-4def-a457-944bebb9111a" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="451" height="95" backcolor="#000000"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="c2fa629b-41e3-4ea6-ba69-458367963aac" style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="451" height="66"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Call Tracker Report]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="a01a3826-af92-4941-ab2b-41cb1da3f9a6" style="SubTitle" x="157" y="66" width="249" height="29"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[X-ONT Software (Ltd) Ltd]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="3d131a89-bb0f-4d0a-8085-85ef01af5910" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="96" width="451" height="21" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CC0000"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement uuid="580213d0-b1fc-4725-b311-c89e960a4ce0" x="303" y="1" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="99c5e0a7-c15a-4072-b1ff-8b83a347f161" x="2" y="121" width="74" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer  ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="cfe1a411-8270-4b02-947c-a699ff86c385" x="205" y="121" width="56" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Called By]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="bc57e2ae-3f68-4376-9d87-97c2c984a679" x="363" y="121" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Called Taken By]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ba3f773c-9145-4e37-9ffe-70dc2e1acefd" x="204" y="143" width="65" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Report Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="948a2d75-1716-414e-b2e9-4b3ab44382ca" x="2" y="143" width="74" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Group Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1eb88a37-9aa5-4368-8e4d-fcf02b95a6bb" x="85" y="121" width="67" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[ALL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b4d0efcf-fc10-4cd7-a946-786ee3d7865f" x="284" y="121" width="48" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[ALL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b4d0efcf-fc10-4cd7-a946-786ee3d7865f" x="473" y="121" width="48" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[ALL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="37f5f2ec-f1c2-4837-b0bb-3b4dfde170d0" x="282" y="143" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Detail]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="2be6789f-c973-417f-b32a-44822d417a98" x="84" y="143" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[CustomerCalled]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f40bab96-7309-41d1-a874-f2b99a9f16bc" x="2" y="165" width="74" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date From]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="692e0148-3beb-4c22-b193-36e37254421e" x="205" y="167" width="63" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date To]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                <reportElement uuid="d0e85180-f225-4a6a-ae0d-7927da8212db" x="84" y="167" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateFrom}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="43ea7f44-ebfd-459e-a9c1-dbbe89168f0b" x="282" y="167" width="83" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateTo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3284a455-7c75-40df-838b-34ec9fc5489e" style="Column header" x="297" y="5" width="76" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Satrt]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c41f01fd-3417-4cd2-a8d9-296069637903" style="Column header" x="384" y="5" width="67" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[End]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="95576a18-8fe1-4d57-bef4-c3361481475c" style="Column header" x="107" y="5" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CallTakenBy]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1ff784cc-a3ab-4f0e-931d-6924a48e5299" style="Column header" x="199" y="5" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="4c7fd897-81e9-4711-99d1-de26c6f86a47" style="Column header" x="2" y="4" width="92" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Called By]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6033972d-b1d4-4154-9df2-24cba2a403dd" style="Column header" x="471" y="5" width="58" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Duration]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="ccc5fd50-0293-441b-b783-e95672e038a1" style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="18"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="h.mm a">
                    <reportElement uuid="a317f374-5796-43c4-99d6-10a3af7ee4db" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="297" y="0" width="92" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CallStart}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="442d310e-4052-4ccb-96e0-636b268a55e7" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="107" y="0" width="92" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CallTakenBy}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd-MMM-yy">
                    <reportElement uuid="74fca3b3-8be6-40b5-8556-eddf64295fd3" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="199" y="0" width="92" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CalledDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="2dcf814d-af5b-4aa9-9fb3-a70948156bf3" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="2" y="0" width="92" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CallPersonName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="###0">
                    <reportElement uuid="b0db0027-f5f2-4126-a400-16e0b5a1d0ba" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="481" y="0" width="48" height="18"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Duration}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="h.mm a">
                    <reportElement uuid="89479c74-1d4f-4e50-bc8c-3577a6081433" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="389" y="0" width="92" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CallEnd}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="4de509a0-2c1a-494e-80ba-26495de7e795" positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField pattern="###0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="daab26a1-72f8-48bb-aea6-3265520641c2" x="458" y="4" width="71" height="20" forecolor="#990000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{duration_tot}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="aecf8666-74fc-4ff3-8a1b-3a4e548d5d69" x="307" y="4" width="149" height="20" forecolor="#990000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Net Total Minutes]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="57d220fb-781d-4991-a9e4-1b7006fea841" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="555" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#000000"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement uuid="59953dfc-6b53-4411-a003-74cd5d551432" style="Column header" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="8a2577bd-ce1b-47e5-87bf-74e7627e89a3" style="Column header" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement uuid="c36f2f3c-cae1-4e1a-889e-37c3a5862d5f" style="Column header" x="2" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This is what I run:

```
     JasperReport jasperReport = null;
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("dateFrom", dateFrom);
        parameters.put("dateTo", dateTo);
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
        System.out.println("==Path==" + path);
        String filePath = path+"\\classes\\com\\crmreport\\controller\\BusinessUnitDetail.jrxml";
         System.out.println("==filePath==" + filePath);
        jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(filePath);
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        byte[] byteStream = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline, filename=BusinessUnitDetail.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(byteStream.length);
        outStream.write(byteStream,0,byteStream.length);
```

What causes these errors?  I googled it, it say error is on XML.  But it worked fined using iReport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the jrxml file has been added to your jar file, you should load it like this:

```
InputStream is = ReportServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(themeDesignName);
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(is);
```

Comment: Now i am getting following error : `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute value "Column header" of typ e NMTOKEN must be a name token`

Comment: Try removing the white space in the "Column header" style name

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of JasperReport use DOCTYPE. Newer versions use XMLNS. When you opened your .JRXML, the iReport saved it using XMLNS and removed previous DOCTYPE tag, at the beginning of document.
Update your Jasper JARS version, or save your JRXML as older version.