# Not able to get report in .pdf format in java using Jasper and ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jasper Report : Document root element “jasperReport”, must match DOCTYPE root “null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375805/jasper-report-document-root-element-jasperreport-must-match-doctype-root-n)

When I try to run *.jasper* file is created but still I am not able to create **.pdf* report.

My *jrxml* file generated using *iReport version 3.2.1*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="205" y="18" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Testing Jasper Report ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="74" y="9" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="126"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The java code is:

```java
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("field1","ClientName" );
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D://report1.jrxml");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D://sample_report.pdf");
```

The error which i am getting is  :

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1316)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:238)
```

Comment: Hi Alex Sorry to say but i didnt get you what u mean to say