# Getting error Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a project and i am using jasper report to create a report and i have used spring 4.2.

When i am running this project on tomcat it is running fine, but when deploy the same on weblogic i get following error :

```
2017-01-23 19:40:18,520 ERROR [org.apache.commons.digester.Digester] - <Parse Error at line 2 column 434: Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null".>
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:239)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:226)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:214)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:168)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:152)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:150)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Report : Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375805/jasper-report-document-root-element-jasperreport-must-match-doctype-root-n)

Comment: but the same is working in tomcat and not in weblogic

Comment: Maybe you have jars conflict. There are a  lot of similar questions on SO

Comment: You did not provide information to help you

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic was using its own older version of jasper report jar.
I tried to configure that my war file should use its own jars by adding following code in weblogic.xml,

`<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>`

but it didn't work
I solved this issue by adding a new version of jasperreport jar on weblogic server and gave the classpath for the same.